# How to solve msg us-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble using AWS Console on us-west-1 (N. California). On Chrome, I get:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connectionus-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

If I try curl https://us-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/ :

```
$ curl -v https://us-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/
*   Trying 176.32.114.100:443...
* Connected to us-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com (176.32.114.100) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Even with aws-cli:

```
$ AWS_REGION=us-west-1 aws ec2 describe-regions

Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

aws-cli on us-east-1 (N. Virginia) works fine. Accessing console from Chrome also works fine.

Comment: are you using a proxy server?

Comment: @YoussefAbouEgla, no proxy.

Comment: But it definitely looks like some problem with my network. Because I run docker curl from (i)  my PC and (ii) from another server (outside my network) and I get different results. `docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.79.1 -L -v https://us-west-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/`

Comment: I'm trying to narrow it because I don't know the exact setup. The problem is the handshake fails. most probably port mapping if running inside docker. try searching with the error code `error:1408F10B:SSL`

Comment: When switching to 3G, it worked fine. So it was not something related to my software / operating system. It was definitely something with the network. I could not figure out what.